# Multiple-table UPDATE with WHERE not working

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

Can someone help me understand why below UPDATE query produces an ERROR?

```
WITH subt AS (
                SELECT t.portfolio, s.isin, t.quantity, t.date
                    FROM transactions t
                    JOIN stocks s
                        ON t.stock = s.name
                    ORDER BY t.id DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                )

UPDATE holdings h
    JOIN subt
        ON h.portfolio = subt.portfolio
            AND h.isin = subt.isin
    SET h.end_date = DATE_SUB(subt.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    WHERE h.end_date is NULL
```

The error I get:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UPDATE holdings h     JOIN subt       ON h.portfolio =
>   subt.portfolio            AND h.isin ' at line 10

While below SELECT works fine:

```
WITH subt AS (
                SELECT t.portfolio, s.isin, t.quantity, t.date
                    FROM transactions t
                    JOIN stocks s
                        ON t.stock = s.name
                    ORDER BY t.id DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                )

SELECT h.*
FROM holdings h
    JOIN subt
        ON h.portfolio = subt.portfolio
            AND h.isin = subt.isin
    WHERE h.end_date is NULL
```

I'm working with a MariaDB 10 Database via HeidiSQL

Comment: The [_doc on WITH_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/) shows only `SELECT`, not `UPDATE`.  MySQL 8.0 allows `WITH` with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a WITH result you could try using a normal inner join on subquery

```
UPDATE holdings h
JOIN 
  (
            SELECT t.portfolio, s.isin, t.quantity, t.date
                FROM transactions t
                JOIN stocks s
                    ON t.stock = s.name
                ORDER BY t.id DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )  subt
    ON h.portfolio = subt.portfolio
        AND h.isin = subt.isin
SET h.end_date = DATE_SUB(subt.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE h.end_date is NULL
```